# Too many columns in single table - is it good normal form?

Tags: sql-server, normalization

A normalized table should have less number columns and can have reference fields as much as possible.  Is it right approach? 
Is there any relationship between number of columns and a good normalization process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should follow the normalization principles rather than be concerned with the sheer number of columns in a table. The business requirements will drive the entities, their attributes and their relationship and no absolute number is the "correct" one.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there any relationship between
>   number of columns and a good
>   normalization process?

In short, no. A 3NF normalized table will have as many columns as it needs, provided that

> data within the table is dependent
>   on the key, the whole key, and nothing
>   but the key (so help me Codd).

There are situations where (some) denormalization may actually improve performance and the only real measure of when this should be done is to test it.

Comment: +1 for the phrase: "data within the table is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key (so help me Codd)."  What a great line...I am astonished I've never heard it before.  Did you make this up or do you have a source?

Comment: I believe that I first heard it in SQL Server 2005 Bible by Paul Nielsen - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Server-2005-Bible-Paul-Nielsen/dp/0764542567/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1233667734&sr=8-1

I just did a search and couldn't find the phrase, but am almost certain it was from here

Comment: I'm pretty sure the phrase is much older than that.  I had a database course at business school (yes, it was a strange course), and the teacher would use that phrase all the time.  This was in 1995.

Comment: @LuckyLindy - The phrase is probably older than me, but the first time I heard it was a while ago, I believe in SQL Server 2005 bible (although I'm starting to doubt that now. I've read too many SQL/DB books to keep track, to be honest) :)

Comment: I heard it at least 13 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach you can use if you feel your table has too many fields.  Example:-

```
CREATE TABLE Person
    Person_ID int not null primary key,
    Forename nvarchar(50) not null,
    Surname nvarchar(50) not null,
    Username varchar(20) null,
    PasswordHash varchar(50) null
```

This table represents people but clearly not all people need be users hence the Username and PasswordHash fields are nullable.  However its possible that there will be 1 or 2 orders of magnitude more people than there are users.

In such case we could create a User table to hold the Username and PasswordHash fields with a one-to-one relationship to the Person table.

You can generalise this approach by looking for sets of nullable fields that either null together of have values together and significantly likely to be null.  This indicates that there is another table you could extract.

**Edit**

Thanks to Stephanie (see comments) this technique is apparently called "Vertical Partitioning"

Comment: At least tell him the name of this technique: Vertical Partitioning.

Comment: @Stephanie: Why is that important?

Comment: Well since I doubt you've completely exhausted the entire body of knowledge known about Vertical Partitioning, the OP may want to, gee, I don't know, Google it. Google won't come back with good answers for, "That thing that AnthonyWJones said on SO" but will for  Vertical Partitioning. If I had more rep, I woulda fixed it for you.

Comment: @Stephanie:  Thank you, of course for me to be able to do that I would have to have known that that's what its called.  I spend most of time coding using common sense, some time later I find out that a certain pattern I use have been given names by the clever people.  Try to use less challanging comments in future, that don't include other assumptions like "the stupid answerer withheld something he knew and is clearly of value".  For example the simple comment "This technique is known as Vertical Partitioning" would have been far better, less personal and would reflect on you better.

Comment: May I say this can also be seen as Single Responsibility Principal (SRP). Depending on the domain a person can be understood as a name, age, sex and avatar. User holds then a very different use which is authentication and is usually linked to an email which may change hands at some time.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with @ocdecio, I would also observe that a database that is normalized will generally have fewer columns per table and more tables than one that is not, given the same data storage requirements.  Similar to code smells a database smell would be relatively few tables given a reasonably large application.  This would be a hint that perhaps your data is not in normal form.  Applying normalization rules, where appropriate, would alleviate this "smell".

Comment: That is true; what I wanted to point out is that if you follow the roles you might not see the denormalized version of your database. And it is true, the feeling of "too many columns" is a good smell indicator of bad normalization.

Comment: I agree that it may be a "reasonable" indicator, but nothing more. I just had a look at some of the tables in the Cisco IPCC database schema and there are 90+ columns in some tables. Granted, there are a number of persisted computed columns, but I think the point that I'm trying to make is...

Comment: that the nature of the data will dictate the number of columns in tables (in my example, VoIP telephony platform). BTW, The Cisco IPCC database schema is reasonably normalized.

Comment: I agree that, in two databases targeting the same problem, the one that is properly normalized will have fewer columns per table than one that is not.  I'd almost hate to tell this to newbies, though, as they'll just make tables w/ fewer columns, point and say: "look, normalized!" *slaps forehead*

Comment: "a database smell would be relatively few tables given a reasonably large application." I would insert before Database. "OLTP" or "3NF". This is not code smell for all "database"'s in general.

Comment: I like the phrase "smell" - exactly the right mental image. I've come across a fair number of databases that really stink - some Seibel implementations for example. Column creep is a real problem for databases that have been around a long time. Sure, it often means the code doesn't break but it's one area where I think agile refactoring should be applied

Answer (score 0):

Each column must have a direct and exclusive relationship to the primary key. If you have an attribute-heavy item that there is only so much you can do to simplify the model. Any attempt to split into multiple tables will be counter-productive and pointless.